# Why are services not injected in generated controllers when the length of the class name is one?

Tags: grails, scaffolding

In Grails 4.0.3 and Grails 3.3.11, if you have a domain class named `A`, e.g.

```
package mypackage

abstract class A {
  String name
  // ...
  // properties
  // ...
}
```

And you populate it in `Bootstrap.groovy`, e.g.

```
package mypackage

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        A.withTransaction { status ->
            A.saveAll( 
                new A( name: "a1" ),
                new A( name: "a2" ),
                new A( name: "a3" )
            )
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

If you use scaffolding (`create-scaffold-controller A`), everything works correctly.

But if you delete the scaffolding controller and `generate-all` for your class `A`, everything fails throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` because the `AService aService` object is `null` in `AController.groovy`, i.e. the service object is not properly injected in the controller.

---

If you delete all the generated files except the domain class file (`A.groovy`), rename the file and the class as, let's say, `A1`, and `generate-all` again, everything works!

You can try with any one-letter named classes, e.g. `A`, `B`, `X`, etc., and the generated code always fails for the same reason. Add another character to the class name, regenerate, and everything works!

I suppose there must be some name clash somewhere when a class is named with a single character.

Posted at https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

> Why are services not injected in generated controllers when the length
>   of the class name is one?

The issue has less to do with the length of the class name and more to do with how the bean names are generated if the class name begins with all upper case letters.  If you have a service class named `AService`, the bean name will be `AService`, not `aService`.  This is because if everything before the artifact type (`Service` in this case) is all upper case, the bean name will also begin with upper case letters.  Some relevant tests are at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/fcc975df7815bb62b392b6fb59efd2e4fcace279/grails-bootstrap/src/test/groovy/grails/util/GrailsNameUtilsTests.groovy#L92-L95.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my mother language, but do you mean that you cannot name classes with only one letter in Grails if you want to use static scaffolding? BTW, class `AService` is automatically generated by `generate-all A` and, as you say, the generated bean inside the controller is named `aService`, but it is `null`.

Comment: "...and, as you say, the generated bean inside the controller is named aService, but it is null" - That is correct.  The bean name is `AService`, not `aService` which is why the `aService` property is not being initialized.  When using autowire by name the bean name has to match the property name.

Comment: I believe these two class values are referred to as 'realName' and 'logicalName' if I'm not mistaken. This is a common mistake to confuse the two.